# How to use f-Literal with PartiQL in AWS and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I want to use PartiQL to query a DynamoDB table with boto3.
I works perfectly, when I use it like this:

```
stmt = "SELECT * FROM Onlineshop WHERE PK= 'c#12345'"
resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(Statement= stmt)
```

But when I replace some values in the select statement with a f-literal it fails.

```
PK = 'c#12345'
table_name = 'Onlineshop'
stmt = f' "SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE PK= {PK}" '
resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(Statement= stmt)
```

What could be the reason?

Thank you in advance

W

Comment: Don't construct SQL queries using string formatting. `execute_statement` almost certainly supports parameterized queries.

Comment: Your *immediate* problem is that you are including the double quotes that used to *define* the `str` literal as *literal characters* in the new `str` value.

Comment: @chepner  it almost works with the parameterized  version, just cant replace the table name with it. Any hint?

Comment: I know `psycopg2` provides some additional extensions for safely constructing queries; I don't know about `dynamodb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The originally-accepted answer suffers from a potential SQL injection problem so I've added this alternate answer. You should always pass parameters safely.

```
PK = "c#12345"

resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(
    Statement="SELECT * FROM Onlineshop WHERE PK=?",
    Parameters=[
        {
            "S": PK
        }
    ]
)
```

Arguably, you could inject the table name `Onlineshop` via f-string, as in the OP's original self-answer, but that's only safe if the table name was not provided by a user (or other external entity). I'd personally prefer to see the table name hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

well I found out how it works. Here the solution for anybody who wants to use this kind of query on dynamodb:

```
PKey = 'c#12345'
table_name = 'Onlineshop'
stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE PK= '{PKey}' "
resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(Statement= stmt)
```